# Error deploying Rails app to Opsworks using unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, unicorn, aws-opsworks

The application gets successfully deployed but it does not work!

The error file at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows the following error:

```
2014/07/27 13:01:33 [crit] 13633#0: *531 connect() to unix:/srv/www/webcam_app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.21.187, server: webcam_app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/srv/www/webcam_app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock:/", host: "172.31.0.13"
```

I checked and found that `unicorn.conf` does not exist in `/srv/www/webcam_app/shared/sockets`.

I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Do I need to add any gem for unicorn ar is it some kind of problem with the cookbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
# Use unicorn as the web server
gem 'unicorn'
```

to Gemfile solved the problem.